# How I can dynamically add HTML with if /else or swtich/case conditions

Tags: html, jquery, if-statement, insert, switch-statement

**What I'm trying to do** :

I want to create an html code generator. The idea is to be able to create an email skeleton, with the possibility for the user, via inputs, to modify certain data, such as the title of the document, the size of the blocks etc.  There is an html block that appears as soon as the page loads. Then the user can add additional html blocks clicking on buttons.

**What I managed to do:**

For now and after several attempts, I come up with a certain result: I can modify the variables in the generated code when the page loads. I can add html blocks when clicking on the buttons..

The user can set a size, and click on the button, the defined size will be indicated in the width attribute of the block. But if I change the size without clicking the button, it doesn't update the width attribute on these dynamic blocks.

What I want to do is to be able to modify the "width" variable on these dynamic html blocks by modifying the input directly. For the moment the update of the "width" field modifies the value of the width, only on the default content.

I put here a minimal code to reproduce the bug I face and to show where I am. Any help would be welcome, especially to improve the code

**The code:**

```js
var id='';
    var component='';
    var title ='' ;
    var width = '';
    $('.component').on('click',function(){
        id= $(this).attr('id');
             switch(id){
           case 'block_one':      
            component+= '<div style="width:'+width+'px"><p>Lorem</p></div>';
            break;
            case 'block_two':
            component += '<div style="width:'+width+'px"><p>my second block</p></div>'; 
            break
        }           
    })
    
    function build_page() { 
         title = $('#title').val();
        width = $('#width').val();
        var code='<!DOCTYPE html>\n'
            +' <html>\n'
            +' <head>\n'
            +'  <title>'+title+'</title>\n'
            +' </head>\n'
            +' <body>\n'
            +' <div>\n'
            +'<h1>This is my title page : '+title+'</h1>\n'
            +'<div style="width:'+width+'px"><p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod\n'
            +' tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,\n'
            +' quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo\n'
            +' consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse\n'
            +' cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non\n'
            +' proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p></div>\n'
        
            code += component;  
            code +=' </body>\n'
            +' </html>'
            $('#output').html(code);
    }
    build_page();
    
    $( "input, select" ).on('change',function() {           
        build_page();
    });
    $('button').on('click', function() {
        build_page();
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <aside>
      <div>
        <label for="title">Title</label>
        <input type="text" name="title" id="title" value="Mytitle">
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for="width">Width</label>
        <input type="number" name="width" id="width" value="600">
      </div>
      <div id="component-filter">
        <button type="button" class="component" id="block_one">add first block</button>
        <button type="button" class="component" id="block_two">add second block</button>
      </div>
  </aside>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div id="output"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

If I insert the condition inside my function, with a switch/case or an if/else, it works but halfway. I can change the size by changing the corresponding input, but now when I click on the buttons to add blocks, it replaces the previous one, instead of adding.
Any help would be appreciated !

```js
var id='';
var component='';
var title ='' ;
var width = '';
$('.component').on('click', function(){
    id= $(this).attr('id');
})

function build_page() { 
    title = $('#title').val();
    width = $('#width').val();
    var code='<!DOCTYPE html>\n'
        +' <html>\n'
        +' <head>\n'
        +'  <title>'+title+'</title>\n'
        +' </head>\n'
        +' <body>\n'
        +' <div>\n'
        +'<h1>This is my title page : '+title+'</h1>\n'
        +'<div style="width:'+width+'px"><p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod\n'
        +' tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,\n'
        +' quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo\n'
        +' consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse\n'
        +' cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non\n'
        +' proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p></div>\n'
         switch(id){
            case 'block_one':     
            code += '<div style="width:'+width+'px"><p>Lorem</p></div>';
            break;
            case 'block_two':
            code += '<div style="width:'+width+'px"><p>my second block</p></div>'; 
            break
        }
            
        code +=' </body>\n'
        +' </html>'
        $('#output').html(code);
}
build_page();

$( document).on('input','input,select', function() {          
    build_page();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <aside>
      <div>
        <label for="title">Title</label>
        <input type="text" name="title" id="title" value="Mytitle">
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for="width">Width</label>
        <input type="number" name="width" id="width" value="600">
      </div>
      <div id="component-filter">
        <button type="button" class="component" id="block_one">add first block</button>
        <button type="button" class="component" id="block_two">add second block</button>
      </div>
  </aside>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div id="output"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Add some liberal `console.log("start")` / `console.log("component click")` etc so that you can see what's happening and get a better understanding of how events work.  Your `.component` click event does not (and cannot) execute while `code` is building, so does nothing as it runs later.  Move the event outside `build` (where it belongs) and see if it still makes sense.

Comment: In fact when the button is clicked, the html block should be added to the code variable, but this is not the case. In the console, the block is added at the very end of the template (after the body tag) while I do not have an append function. And although it appears in console, it does not stand out in front.